# Laravel, validate integers in steps of 10

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to validate a number in laravel. What's supposed to happen is that the number can only increase in 10 fold.

As an example:

```
10:    Valid number
11:    invalid number
11,5:  invalid number
15:    invald number
20:    valid number
140:   valid number
```

The rule's I have set up in my request look like this:

```
"amount" => ["required", "numeric", new UserHasPrivatePublicBalance(), "gte:10"],
```

Does Laravel have a built in rule for something like that? Or could someone point me in the right direction of how to validate such a thing in plain PHP so I can create a custom rule?

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to create a custom rule for where `$number % 10 == 0`, ie the number is divisible by 10.

Comment: Your laravel version?

Comment: if you want a hacky way you can do `regex:/^\d+0$/` but it may not work for JSON requests since numbers in JSON are actual numbers and not numeric strings.

Answer (score 9):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#using-closures

For your case

```
'amount' => [
    'required',
    'numeric',
    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        if ($value % 10 !== 0) {
            $fail($attribute.' must be 10 divisible.'); // your message
        }
    },
],
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no built in validation rule for doing this, but to check if a number is divisible by 10 you could do:

```
if($number % 10 != 0) {
  return false;
}
```

The modulus operator `%` returns the remainder of a division, so the result will always be 0 if the number is divisible by 10.